# Get db call inside pytest FastAPI

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

So what I'm trying to do is get the test user that im creating while testing to delete at the end but I get the error: `FAILED tests_main.py::test_delete_new_users - AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'`

This is my code:

```
def test_delete_new_users(db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    auth = client.post('/token',
                       data={'username': 'test123', 'password': 'test123'}
                       )
    access_token = auth.json().get('access_token')
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.username == 'test123').first()

    response = client.post('/user/delete/' + user.user_id,
                           headers={
                               'Authorization': 'bearer' + access_token
                           })
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Do I need to make a separate API call to retrieve this user for instance make an api called get_user_id_with_username where I will pass username as attribute or is there a way where I can make a db call within a pytest because from what I read I can only use Depends on API calls. Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you that your `db = Depends(...)` object has no attribute `query`, therefor `db.query(models.User)` errors out. It doesn't look like your `Depends` function is working correctly, because it is not the database object that you expect.

Comment: You can't use `Depends` in a test definition - `Depends` only gets resolved (recursively) from a view endpoint inside FastAPI. My suggestion is to retrieve the user from an API endpoint instead (or if you need to, use a pytest fixture to give you a db session you can work with). Generally using the defined http API would be preferred.

Comment: Create a separate fixture to take care of the db session for unit testing.

Comment: @MatsLindh so u sugest to make like I mentioned above an API from which I will retrieve that user from its username ?

Comment: For example (generally from the id, and generally only for those users that have access). I'd also suggest replacing `/delete/` in the URL with using the `delete` HTTP method instead; it makes a cleaner and easier to read API (you'd do `client.delete('/users/{user.user_id}')` instead of POST-ing against a specific path that contains delete)